# Entity Framework run migrate.exe in single user mode

Tags: entity-framework, t-sql

In t-sql I can execute following to initiate single user mode

```
ALTER DATABASE AdventureWorks2012
SET SINGLE_USER
WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;
```

How can I tell/configuure EF `migrate.exe` to run in single user mode?